# CodeIgniter Subquery in Query Builder

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, query-builder

Is there a way or can someone translate this to code igniter query builder.

```
SELECT result.id, result.name, result.added
FROM (SELECT tbl.id, tbl.name, tbl.date_added
      FROM table tbl
      GROUP BY tbl.id) result
GROUP BY result.date_added
```

I already have my research(link below) but can't find anything like this(query above).
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-write-subqueries-in-codeigniter-active-record/

And yes, this can be done using Stored Procedure but I have another reason why I need to implement this as query builder.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
// Sub Query
         $this->db->select('result.id, result.name, result.added')->from('table tbl');
     $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

// Main Query
     $this->db->select('result.id, result.name, result.added')
     ->from('table tbl')
     ->where("id IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE)
     ->get()
     ->result();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already read the article of your answer which was the link I included in my Question. 
https://arjunphp.com/how-to-write-subqueries-in-codeigniter-active-record/